# Loop fetches all the words in 1 input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

as you can see in the picture below, my words 'es' and 'presso' are put into one input field instead of 'es' in one and 'presso' in another input field. 
[image]

how my JSON looks like:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "Example",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "Example",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "espresso",
      "syllables": [
        "es",
        "presso",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
}
}
```

This is how my loop looks like:

```
$.map(exercise, function(exercise, i) {
$("#addOpdracht").click();
$(".exerciseGetWordInput_" + i).val(exercise.word) // starts with 0

var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {
 console.log(exer.syllables);

$(".syllable" + s).val(exer.syllables);
});

});
```

to zoom in on the loop where I fetch the `syllables`:

```
  var exerSyll = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {
 console.log(exer.syllables);

$(".syllable" + s).val(exer.syllables);
});
```

the function where I create the `syllable inputs`:

```
function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
 cValue = cValue || '';
 var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
'class': 'form-group form-control syllable' + SyllablesID++,
'type': 'text',
'value': cValue,
'placeholder': 'Syllables',
'name': 'Syllablescounter['+ SyllablesID++ +']'
 });
 return wpInput;
}
```

what is it that I am doing wrong? (I did declare the variable `SyllablesID` so don't worry about that part).

Comment: you are looping on the exercises here `$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {` and for each exercise you set the input value with `exer.syllables` which is an array. The result is concatenation with `,`. You need to loop on syllabes too

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "Example",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "Example",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "espresso",
      "syllables": [
        "es",
        "presso",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
}
};


function draw(data){
  
  for (ex of data.main_object.main_object.exercises){
       for( sy of ex.syllables){
         $("#container").append(`<input type="text" value="${sy}">`)
       }
  }
}

draw(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><div>
```

`syllables` is an array as per to posted `JSON` so you'll have to get each value and add it as a value to the input element. You can again use `.map` or `for/forEach` etc to loop through syllabus array and add the array entries to input values

```
$.map(exerSyll, function(exer, s) {
 console.log(exer.syllables);

 $.map(exer.syllables, function(syll, i){
   $(".syllable" + i).val(syll);
})

});
```

Comment: when I use ur code (Still appreciate it very much so thank you), it displays only the first syllable. how come it doesn't show the second value?

Comment: amm.. don't know why. can you share a working snippet ?

Comment: Honest answer? I have never worked with a snippet and from what I just tried it should be illegal for me to work with them. Is there another way I could possibly provide you with more information? I assume a jsfiddle won't help?

Comment: Yes. And I already mentioned that in answer. Just wrote it in flow. bad habit :p

Comment: @D.Sof there is nothing wrong using `jsfiddles`. That's why they are there to show code simulations etc. Anyways, I've created a dummy code which does the same more or less. You can get an idea with this.

Comment: The problem is: I don't think the fiddle reproduces the problem since I click on a edit button and it should then fetch the data back into input fields so you can actually edit